# Need help submitting form data without using forms.py

Tags: python, django

I started learning django few days ago. I'm currently working on a django form inside Bootstrap modal and I can't seem to submit my form data to the database. Can tell me what is the issue? Btw, I'm not using django *forms.py*.

**index.html**

```
<div class="modal-content">
            <form action="" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="modal-header">
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'aclapp'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('aclapp/', views.index, name='index'),
    path('submit/', views.submit, name='submit'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def submit(request):
if (request.method == 'POST'):
    name = request.POST['name']
    user_id = request.POST['user_id']
    email = request.POST['email']
    section = request.POST['section']
    status = request.POST['status']
    roles = request.POST['roles']

    user = UserDetail(name=name, user_id=user_id, email=email, section=section, status=status, roles=roles)
    user.save()

    return redirect('/index.html')
else:
    return redirect('/index.html')
```

Here's my GitHub project files: https://github.com/josephsim/django-access-control-list

**EDIT**

Thank you to everyone that reached out to me with your suggestions. I've managed to fix this issue. Turns out the **urls.py** and the form **action** attribute was the problem. I fixed it by doing this:

[form action in index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJWnI.png)

[urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Afdl.png)

Comment: You didn't define form action url

Comment: @ShwetaChandel that's not necessary, it will post the to the same url (default behaviour of HTML forms, cf the HTML specs).

Comment: May I kindly suggest you stop there and learn to properly use Django (including forms and the contrib.auth app) first ? It will save you a lot of time, pain and frustration. As to "what is the issue", it's impossible to tell from something like "I can't seem to submit my form data to the database" - you'll have to first do some basic debugging first (trace http request / responses in your browser, trace your view code execution etc) and report what you've found.

Comment: Can you please tell us what is the error raised ? I would suggest you to add `print()` for each variable and check the console and see are the fields submitted or not, try tracing your code and check where is the issue.